# Web Application works locally - 504 error remotely

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, firewall, http-status-code-504

I have a site (ASP.NET WebForms) hosted on IIS7.  I have a static IP.  My router is pointed at the right computer IP on my network.  And the site works fine both on the server and on computers on the same network when I go to the interal IP of the server.  However, when I try to access the site remotely via the static IP or the domain name, I get a 504 timeout error.

I have absolutely no idea where to begin, because the 504 error gives me no information as to what the problem is.  Port 80, which is the port this is on, is open for inbound firewall rules... It wasn't for outbound, but I opened that to test it, and it still didn't work.

Other than that, I'm out of ideas.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It means you have deployed your web at your home. When you are trying to call at Intranet using the domain name or static IP address your are able to do so, but when your try to access on Internet you cant.
The solution which I can see for that is because on Internet, It dose not recognize your static IP address you need to pass your dynamic IP of your ISP.

Go [here](http://whatismyipaddress.com/) this will tell your IP information something like : **202.147.18.194** and instead of passing your static machine IP pass this IP when you are trying to access over internet. The URL of your web would be something like this:

"http://202.147.18.194/MyWeb/index.asp"